# How do I regex match (Non inclusive)?

Tags: java, regex

I want to get the String between (not including): alt=" and "
Here is a small sample of my code:

```
Pattern p2 = compile("alt=\"(.*?)\");
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(result);
while (m2.find()) {
    names.add(m2.group());
}
```

The output is for example: alt="Harry Potter"
when I want the output to be just: Harry Potter

Comment: Use `compile("alt=\"(.*?)\"")` and `m2.group(1)`, but to parse HTML, you'd better use some HTML parser.

Comment: Or you can use lookaround: `(?<=alt=").*?(?=")` and avoid dealing with capture groups. But you should really use a HTML parser.

Comment: Brilliant @wiktor thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a typo (a missing double quote in `compile`) and the group you need to access is Group 1 (use `compile("alt=\"(.*?)\"")` and `m2.group(1)`).

You should think about using an HTML parser for getting values from HTML, like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). Here is a way to get what you need with it:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html_contents);
for (Element element : doc.getAllElements())
{
    for (Attribute attribute : element.attributes())
    {
        if(attribute.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("alt"))
        {
            names.add(attribute.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```